# Zuul Proxy Routing to WebSocket service

Tags: node.js, websocket, netflix-zuul

I am using Eureka and Zuul Proxy services for load balancing and routing the application traffic to my microservices. I have one WebSocket server which is in Node.js. The service got successfully registered in Eureka. Just like my normal HTTP Zuul routing, I added a property for websocket service as well.

```
zuul.routes.ws.path=/wsservice/**
zuul.routes.ws.serviceId=<my-websocket-service>
```

But Zuul is not routing to websocket service. Is it not possible to use Zuul proxy to connect with websocket service? I also referred this link [Websocket over Spring Netflix Zuul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32078779/websocket-over-spring-netflix-zuul) where they said, it is not possible to use Websocket protocol overl Zuul.

So, how can I use Zuul proxy for Websocket service?

Thanks for the help in advance.